# Design Pattern for handling arguments in external interfaces with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

Let's say I have a function, within which I am accessing an interface (in this case mongoose) that I can't change. The interface returns a promise that just passes in the found resource;

```
show = function(response) {
  Resource.findById(req.params.id).then(renderResource);
}

function renderResource(resource) {
  // render the response
}
```

In order to render the response, I need to have access to the `response` parameter from the `show` function. I can get this in using the `bind` function, hijacking `this` to be the response variable;

```
show = function(response) {
  Resource.findById(req.params.id).then(renderResource.bind(response));
}

function renderResource(resource) {
  this.send(resource);
}
```

But what if I want to pass another argument into the `renderResource` function? The only way I've managed to do it is like this;

```
show = function(response) {
  Resource.findById(req.params.id).then(function(resource) {
    renderResource.call(response, resource, "foo"));
  }
}

function renderResource(resource, otherArg) {
  this.send(resource);
  //do something with otherArg
}
```

But at this point I am no longer happy with the code because;

- I have had to declare a function literal, and are well on our way to callback hell.
- I am using `call` purely so I can still use `this` in the function, but actually by the time we're this far I may as well just pass in `response` as a third arg.

I am certain that there must be a pattern or something to deal with this problem in a neater way, without having to declare a new function literal. Can anyone suggest a pattern? is there a neater way of dealing with this situation?

Comment: Using function literals has nothing to do with callback hell - you don't have to nest them when working with promises. Closures are totally fine, and the recommended approach for your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass as many arguments to `bind` as you need.  I would avoid using `this` as a way to pass arguments to avoid confusion.

```
show = function(response) {
  Resource.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(renderResource.bind(null, response, "foo"));
}

function renderResource(response, otherArg, resource) {
  response.send(resource);
  //do something with otherArg
}
```

See `bind` documentation for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

This is known as partical application:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application